# Batteryless laptop won't power on properly

Tags: boot, laptop, battery, power

My gf has an ASUS R556L. It's around 3 years old so it's out of warranty.
A while ago I had to remove the battery because it has swollen and I didn't want to risk it. The battery in that model is not really 'removable' - I had to open the laptop to remove it.
It was working fine for a few months on AC power only with no issues but now it's not so fine and I can't figure out what's happening.

It has trouble starting up. After pressing the power button the fans come online and the LEDs light up but then nothing happens. Screen stays off, the HDD is not working (the light isn't blinking and you can't hear it spinning). The HDD light blinks briefly after powering on but then it stops and never lights up again. Only thing you can do is either pull the plug or hold the power button to force it to power off.
After a lot of tries it will eventually start and it will work fine, but it seems to take longer and longer to start each time. Once it's on - it's 100% fine. You can even reboot it no problem, but only if you use the reboot function. If you power down for even a second, it will take ages to start again.
My gf has been keeping it in sleep mode for days because of this. We're short on cash right now so I can't replace the battery, but even then, I'd like to know if anything is wrong with it.

Where do I even start diagnosing this?

I tried holding the power button down when the laptop is unplugged. Doesn't help. I tried restarting it quickly, tried waiting for it to warm up. Tried unplugging it every time before restart, tried keeping it constantly plugged in. Nothing helps and nothing changes. When it's on - there seems to be nothing wrong with it.

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities, so this one will be tough to figure out on a Q&A site.  One possibility is the boot area of the drive has become corrupted.  A way to test that would be to boot a live Linux session on a USB flash drive or DVD.  If that boots fine, it would point to the hard drive.  You could also check the SMART statistics on the hard drive and run chkdsk.  Finding the problem will take detective work of ruling things out.

Comment: OK, I'll try doing that. Thanks for the directions.